# How to keep a diagonal running background animation without rotating the div?

Tags: css, css-transforms, css-animations

I have created an animation where a background image moves from left to the right. I want this animation to go diagonal so I've turned the div 45 degrees using: `-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);`

[The result looks like this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C65hY/)

As you can see, the div is turned (red border), but I want the div not to rotate. So how can I keep the diagonal animation without rotating the div?

Thanks

1. ps for demo purposes I've only used the -webkit- prefix
2. ps2 I can only modify one div with the css, so adding another div is
   not possible

Comment: why cant you add another div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pseudo elements to accomplish what you want:

html:

```
<div id='test'></div>
```

css:

```
#test:before
{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    z-index: -1;
    background: url(background.png) 0 0 repeat;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    background-image: url("http://www.easyvectors.com/assets/images/vectors/afbig/green-left-double-arrows-set-clip-art.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    -moz-animation: swim 2s linear 0s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: swim 2s linear 0s infinite;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#test {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    height:300px;
    border: 3px solid red;
}

@-webkit-keyframes swim {
    from { background-position: 200% 0, 0 0; }
    to  { background-position: 100% 0, 0 0; }
}
```

## <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C65hY/37/)</kbd>

Check out this great [article](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-transform-background-image/) by    Craig Buckler for more information.